# Datalab: How to export Big Query standard SQL query to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

Within a datalab notebook it's possible to export BiqQuery results directly into a dataframe. I have an example that works for legacy SQL and I need to adjust to make it work for standard SQL. I can't find a syntax that works for this. Here's what I think I need to write:

```
import datalab.bigquery as bq
import pandas as pd

%%sql --module data_name -d standard
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170126' AND '20170126'

my_data_frame = bq.Query(data_name).to_dataframe()
```

Something must be wrong with this syntax as I get the error:

```
Exception: invalid: Invalid table name: `project.dataset.table.ga_sessions_*`
```

How can I fix this to work for Standard SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need to make it explicit that you want to use Standard SQL [in datalab](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/949).

Let us know if this works for you (make sure your branch is up-to-date with the master branch):

```
my_data_frame = bq.Query(data_name).to_dataframe(dialect='standard')
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this %%sql magic has been supplanted by the %%bq magic, and standard sql is now the default:

[Migration guide](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/wiki/%60datalab%60-to-%60google.datalab%60-Migration-Guide)